# Python Requests / Sessions using generated cookie

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I'm trying to create a bot that checks for open classes, the webpage uses a cookie that is set when visiting the site. However I cant seem to replicate this using requests/sessions with my code.

What it's supposed to do:

1. visit [link 1](https://csprd-web.psg.umbc.edu/psc/csprdg/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL) (creates the cookie) (search page)
2. visit [link 2](https://csprd-web.psg.umbc.edu/psp/csprdg/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?%3FICAJAX=1&ICNAVTYPEDROPDOWN=1&ICType=Panel&ICElementNum=0&ICStateNum=1&ICAction=CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH&ICXPos=0&ICYPos=0&ResponsetoDiffFrame=-1&TargetFrameName=None&FacetPath=None&ICFocus=&ICSaveWarningFilter=0&ICChanged=-1&ICAutoSave=0&ICResubmit=0&ICSID=f9idQbPFQhGJWS62tiUY7e6ACwGshWm6a1X8ugGaLyU=&ICActionPrompt=false&ICBcDomData=C~HC_CLASS_SEARCH_GBL~EMPLOYEE~HRMS~COMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL~UnknownValue~Class%20Search~UnknownValue~UnknownValue~https%3A%2F%2Fcsprd-web.psg.umbc.edu%2Fpsp%2Fcsprdg%2FEMPLOYEE%2FHRMS%2Fc%2FCOMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL~UnknownValue*F~CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE~EMPLOYEE~HRMS~UnknownValue~UnknownValue~Self%20Service~UnknownValue~UnknownValue~https%3A%2F%2Fcsprd-web.psg.umbc.edu%2Fpsp%2Fcsprdg%2FEMPLOYEE%2FHRMS%2Fs%2FWEBLIB_PT_NAV.ISCRIPT1.FieldFormula.IScript_PT_NAV_INFRAME%3Fpt_fname=CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE&c=RZsUVf7R5IaKU7v2xseI8Q%253d%253d&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE&IsFolder=true~UnknownValue&ICPanelName=&ICFind=&ICAddCount=&ICAPPCLSDATA=&CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_INSTITUTION%2431%24=UMBC1&SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_SUBJECT_SRCH%240=CMSC&SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_ACAD_CAREER%242=UGRD&SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_CATALOG_NBR%241=400&SSR_CLSRCH_WRK_SSR_EXACT_MATCH1%241=G) which includes the search terms in the URL (search results)
3. When done in browser, Link 2 should show the search results

Issue:

- I can create the cookie visiting link 1
- But cant use it with the link 2 that includes the search terms
- this results in loading the same first link (search page)

Here is some sample code I have tried:

```
s = requests.Session()
# create the cookie using first link
r = s.get(url)

# r2 should be search results
r2 = s.post(urlWithSearchTerms, cookies=r.cookies)

# parse html etc, however loads wrong page
data = r2.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Instead of loading the search results, it still loads the first page.

I also tried including r.headers, using sessions.post(url), using without sessions etc..

How would I get python to load the second page?

Thanks!

Comment: you should analyze the HTTP requests sent by a browser session to see what you are missing

Comment: I think you need to send a GET to urlWithSearchTerms rather than a POST.  Also, I don't see why you even need a cookie at all.  I can hit the  urlWithSearchTerms and get search results without sending any cookie.

Comment: @corey Was that using a browser? If so , when you delete cookies and try again it won't load the search results urlWithSearchTerms

Comment: try the get instead of post

Comment: @corey thanks a lot, worked!

Comment: awesome!  i just added this as an answer.  please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending an HTTP POST request where you should be sending a GET.

change this line:

```
r2 = s.post(urlWithSearchTerms, cookies=r.cookies)
```

to:

```
r2 = s.get(urlWithSearchTerms, cookies=r.cookies)
```